# שַׁדַּי, shaday

Tags: language

What is/are any widely accepted Jewish interpretations of the 40+ instances of שַׁדַּי, shaday in the scriptures?  I've seen [conflicting definitions/etymologies](https://HappyHobo.net/2023/02/21/shaddai/) in the Christian world.  Some (the easier to believe) say it means Almighty and is derived from a word meaning power or destruction.  But others say it means "Breast" and that the power/destruction word is derived from it.

In context, it's obvious it's a name of God. But it may have a deeper meaning—which might not be the two contradictory meanings I’ve so far seen. Just like Abraham and Israel are not "only" names but were given because of their meaning.

So I wondered whether Judaic scholars supported one or both of those or even some other explanation.

Comment: It's a name of God. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, in the context, it's obvious it's a name of God.  But it may have a deeper meaning—which might not be the two contradictory meanings I’ve so far seen.  Just like Abraham and Israel are not "only" names but were given because of their meaning.

Comment: I added your comment into the question. Feel free to edit if it doesn't look good to you.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%A9%D6%B7%D7%81%D7%93%D6%B7%D6%BC%D7%99?ven=Carta_Jerusalem%3B_1st_edition,_1987&lang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question. These are the four approaches I found on the subject. This is the way I understand it. I hope they are useful. All text and translation are from seferia

1. Hashem Says to the world stop. Talmud Chagiga

> אָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה אָמַר רַב: בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁבָּרָא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ
> הוּא אֶת הָעוֹלָם, הָיָה מַרְחִיב וְהוֹלֵךְ כִּשְׁתֵּי פַקְעִיּוֹת
> שֶׁל שְׁתִי, עַד שֶׁגָּעַר בּוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וְהֶעֱמִידוֹ,
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״עַמּוּדֵי שָׁמַיִם יְרוֹפָפוּ וְיִתְמְהוּ מִגַּעֲרָתוֹ״,
> וְהַיְינוּ דְּאָמַר רֵישׁ לָקִישׁ: מַאי דִּכְתִיב: ״אֲנִי אֵל שַׁדַּי״
> — אֲנִי הוּא שֶׁאָמַרְתִּי לָעוֹלָם דַּי. אָמַר רֵישׁ לָקִישׁ:
> בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁבָּרָא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אֶת הַיָּם הָיָה מַרְחִיב
> וְהוֹלֵךְ, עַד שֶׁגָּעַר בּוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וְיִבְּשׁוֹ,
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״גּוֹעֵר בַּיָּם וַיַּבְּשֵׁהוּ וְכׇל הַנְּהָרוֹת
> הֶחֱרִיב״.  And Rav Yehuda said that Rav said, with regard to the same
> matter: When the Holy One, Blessed be He, created the world, it
> continued to expand like two balls of a warp, whose cord lengthens as
> they unravel, until the Holy One, Blessed be He, rebuked it and made
> it stand still, as it is stated: “The pillars of heaven tremble and
> are astonished at His rebuke” (Job 26:11). And this is the same as
> that which Reish Lakish said: What is the meaning of that which is
> written: “I am the Almighty God [El Shaddai]” (Genesis 17:1)? It
> means: I am He Who said to the world “enough [dai],” instructing it to
> stop expanding. Similarly, Reish Lakish said: When the Holy One,
> Blessed be He, created the sea, it continued to expand until the Holy
> One, Blessed be He, rebuked it and made it dry, as it is stated: “He
> rebukes the sea and makes it dry, and desiccates all the rivers”
> (Nahum 1:4).
> [https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12a.16?lang=bi](https://%20https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12a.16?lang=bi)

2. Sufficiency for all. Rashi Breshis

> שׁדי. אֲנִי הוּא שֶׁיֵּשׁ דַּי בֶּאֱלֹהוּתִי לְכָל בְּרִיָּה,
> לְפִיכָךְ הִתְהַלֵּךְ לְפָנַי וְאֶהְיֶה לְךָ לֶאֱלוֹהַּ ולְפַטְרוֹן;
> וְכֵן כָּל מָקוֹם שֶׁהוּא בַּמִּקְרָא פֵּרוּשׁוֹ כָּךְ: דַּי שֶׁלּוֹ,
> וְהַכֹּל לְפִי הָעִנְיָן: י I AM GOD ALMIGHTY — I am He whose (ש)
> Godship suffices (די) for every creature (Genesis Rabbah 46:3),
> therefore, ‘‘walk before Me”, and I will be your God and Protector.
> Similarly, wherever in the Scriptures this Divine Name שדי occurs, it
> signifies the idea of His sufficiency — but it all depends upon the
> context as to what the “sufficiency” refers to.

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.1?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=en

3. Hashem is self-sufficient, Rambam

> כן שם ׳יה׳ הוא מענין נצחיות המציאה. ו׳שדי׳ – בו גזרה מן ׳די׳:
> ״והמלאכה היתה דים״; וה׳שין׳ – בענין ׳אשר׳, כמו ״שכבר״; ויהיה ענינו:
> ׳אשר די׳ – הכונה בזה: שהוא לא יצטרך במציאות מה שהמציא ולא בהתמידו,
> לזולתו, אבל מציאותו מספקת בו. וכן שם ׳חסין׳ נגזר מן הכח: ״וחסון הוא
> כאלונים״. וכן ׳צור׳ הוא שם משותף כמו שבארנו.  The name Jah likewise
> implies eternal existence. Shadday, however, is derived from day,
> “enough”; comp. “for the stuff they had was sufficient” (dayyam, Exod.
> 36:7) the shin is equal to asher, “which,” as in she-kebar, “which
> already” (Eccles. 2:16). The name Shadday, therefore, signifies “he
> who is sufficient”; that is to say, He does not require any other
> being for effecting the existence of what He created, or its
> conservation: His existence is sufficient for that. In a similar
> manner the name ḥasin implies “strength”; comp. “he was strong (ḥason)
> as the oaks” (Amos 2:9). The same is the case with “rock,” which is a
> homonym, as we have explained (chap. xvi.).

https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_1.63.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

4. Mighty - Ibin Ezra

> אל שדי. שם התואר וטעמו תקיף וכן כקול שדי. והיה שדי בצריך כי טעמו כטעם
> ושית על עפר בצר. ושדי על משקל לבי דוי. ורבים פירשוהו מגזרת שודד. שהוא
> מנצח והתגבר. וטעם להזכיר השם הזה בפרשה הזאת לירא אברהם וימול. והנכון
> כי השם הנכבד והנורא נקרא כנגדו. וזה שם התאר כנגד המעשה כי העולם עומד
> על אלה שני השמות. והמבין סוד השם יאמין: GOD ALMIGHTY. Shaddai is an
> adjective meaning mighty. Shaddai in like a mighty voice (ke-kol
> shaddai) (Ezek. 1:24) is similar. Also, Shaddai in And mighty will be
> thy silver (shaddai betzarekha) (Job 22:25) is similar because the
> word betzarekha (thy silver) has the same meaning as the word betzer
> (silver) in And lay thy treasure (or silver) (betzer) in the dust (Job
> 22:24). The word Shaddai follows the paradigm of davvai (faint), in
> And my heart is faint (davvai) (Lam. 1:22). Many derive Shaddai from
> the same root as shoded (overpowering), meaning, He is victorious and
> overpowering. The reason God used this name at this time was to
> impress upon Abraham the fear of God so that he would circumcise
> himself. The correct interpretation of the divine names is as follows:
> Shaddai is an adjective describing God’s power over creation. The
> Tetragrammaton, God’s revered and awesome name, stands in contrast to
> it. The world exists by virtue of these two names. Whoever understands
> the secret of God’s name will accept my interpretation.

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.1?lang=he&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en

Answer (score 2):

El Shaddai (אֵל שַׁדַּי)

> This Name depicts God literally as [Sufficiency].  **“Who is Sufficient”** in granting His mercies, and **“Who has Sufficient”** power to give whatever is necessary. (Rashi commentary on [Bereshit 17:1], page 80 of The Schottenstein Edition Interlinear Chumash by ArtScroll)

Comment: Does this cover all cases of שדי or just אל שדי? Are there other opinions?